# Export Selenium script as jar I can run with cmd prompt but no main manifest

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium, junit

```
import static org.junit.Assert.*;
import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import com.thoughtworks.selenium.*;
import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import static org.junit.Assert.*;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Hello extends SeleneseTestCase { 
    private Selenium selenium;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        selenium = new DefaultSelenium("localhost", 4444, "*firefox C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Mozilla Firefox\\firefox.exe", "http://bakersfield.craigslist.org/search/sss?query=plumbers&sort=rel");
        selenium.start();
    }

    @Test
    public void testPlumbers() throws Exception {

    }

    @After
    public void tearDown() throws Exception {
       selenium.stop();
    }

}
```

That is what I currently have, I'm trying to export it but I don't have any main manifest and I can't assign it a class. Really need help, I'd be willing to make a donation to anybody that can TV me and show me how I can make my script an executable .jar that I can run with cmd prompt.

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is create `main` class with `main` method and point out to `test class`.

See my code below:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
JUnit junit = new JUnit();
junit.setTestClasses(new Class[] { Hello.class });
junit.run();
}
```

Hope it helps!